# ASP.NET Core 6.0 DataProtection is delaying the entire service startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0, azure-aks

I have an ASP.NET Core v6.0 app that locally is running smoothly, but when deployed on Azure (AKS) it is really slow to start or doesn't start at all. And this is happening randomly but often.

Looking at some verbose log, it seems that the web app builder and the DI setup is done immediately. Then, when the app starts using `app.Run()` the output console shows some unexpected `DataProtection` logs:

```
// Custom verbose log
11/09/2022 10:17:47 App Run is being called

// runtime log
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
      Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
      Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
      Creating key {1b2ad3d2-7292-49dc-ac55-89bef4c6d015} with creation date 2022-11-09 10:18:04Z, activation date 2022-11-09 10:18:04Z, and expiration date 2023-02-07 10:18:04Z.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {1b2ad3d2-7292-49dc-ac55-89bef4c6d015} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

// Custom IHostedService
warn: ...ServiceBusHostedService[0]
      11/09/2022 10:18:05 scope created
```

Looking at the timestamps, you can clearly see that the application stuck from 10:17:47 to 10:18.04, almost 20 seconds doing apparently nothing.

Then, a custom `IHostedService` implementation starts immediately after (1 second later), but it will be immediately killed because of the startup timeout set to 20 seconds using `webHostBuilder.UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));`.

An overview on the current setup:

Program.cs

```cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

AddAzureAppConfiguration(builder.Configuration);

var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

builder.WebHost.UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); // todo: move up

WebApplication app = builder.Build();
startup.Configure(app, app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>(), app.Lifetime);
app.Run();
```

Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // other stuff
  services.AddHostedService<ServiceBusHostedService>();
}
```

ServiceBusHostedService.cs

```cs
protected ServiceBusHostedService(
  IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
  ILogger<BaseServiceBusHostedService> logger)
{
  _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
  _logger = logger;
}

public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
  ..
}

public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
  ..
  await eventBus.DisposeAsync();
}
```

So, my question is: why does `DataProtection` take so much to run? I think it is looking for some persistent repository until it falls back on the in-memory one, and this operation is *really* time consuming. Is there any way to instruct it to use the in-memory one then? Increasing the shutdown timeout would make the app work but still would not fix the issue.

N.B. I'm aware this IHostedService should be an `BackgroundService` in order to do not block the main hosted service (Kestrel) and it'll be done soon. But this is not solving the delay caused by the `DataProtection`

Comment: Could you fix it? I'm facing a similar issue where my application do not initialize